# prevent user creating if another create unsuccessful django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Probably there is the answer to this question, but I couldn't find it.

How to prevent `User` - `from django.contrib.auth.models import User,` creation if userProfileSerializer creating is unsuccessful. I saw a database transaction is an option but it says

> While the simplicity of this transaction model is appealing, it also
> makes it inefficient when traffic increases. Opening a transaction for
> every view has some overhead. The impact on performance depends on the
> query patterns of your application and on how well your database
> handles locking.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def register(request):
    '''
    Registers user to the server. Input should be in the format:
    {"username": "username", "password": "1234abcd"}
    '''
    # Put the data from the request into the serializer
    serializer = CreateUserSerializer(data=request.data)
    # Validate the data
    if serializer.is_valid():
        # If it is valid, save the data (creates a user).
        serializer.save()
        userProfileSerializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
        userProfileSerializer.context['user_id'] = serializer.data['id']
        userProfileSerializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        userProfileSerializer.save()
```

Serializer classes

```
  class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name',)
            extra_kwargs = {
                'password': {'write_only': True}
            }
    
        def create(self, validated_data):
            user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
            return user
    
    
    class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = UserProfile
            fields = ('title', 'organization', 'user_id')
    
        def create(self, validated_data):
            user_id = self.context["user_id"]
            user_profile = UserProfile(**validated_data, user_id=user_id)
            user_profile.save()
            return user_profile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. check that `UserProfileSerializer` is valid, as you doing already: `userProfileSerializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)`
2. save user serializer as usual after `UserProfileSerializer` is validated: `serializer.save()`

Comment: There is error: `AssertionError: 'commit' is not a valid keyword argument to the 'save()' method. If you need to access data before committing to the database then inspect 'serializer.validated_data' instead.`

Comment: Sorry, my bad - I didn't noticed that you are using DRF serializers, not Django model forms. I edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Their are some ways,

1. use `transaction.atomic`, which you know.
2. delete the created user after `userProfileSerializer` unsuccessfull.
3. Not a way but a trick, Validate both serializers first, confirming everything is all right, then save the user, add user id in profile_serializer, then save the profile_serializer at last. This avoids the transaction.

But it is just a trick; Use transaction as your use case requires it. Its the best way.

Comment: It seems not so bad to use it here. But I cannot use OAuth 2 with a database transaction. There is the error: `error credentials provided `